# Отправка формы заказа на e-mail

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.

Создаю свой сайт и хочу, чтобы с него отправлялась форма заказа на мой e-mail.
В данный момент сайт находится у меня на локальном сервере. Кто знает, как это сделать, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 5):

На Денвере стоит заглушка на функцию mail. На хостинге все должно работать. Или перепишите скрипт под SMTP.

Вот простейший пример с функцией mail:

```
<form method="post" action=""> 
Имя отправителя:<br />
<input type="text" name="user" size="50"><br />
E-mail отправителя:<br />
<input type="text" name="user_email" size="50"><br />
Тема сообщения:<br />
<input type="text" name="subject" size="50"> <br />
Текст сообщения:<br />
<textarea name="text" cols="80" rows="10" ></textarea><br />
<input type="submit" name="send_mail" value="Отправить">
</form>
<?php

if (isset($_POST['send_mail']) && isset($_POST['subject']) && isset($_POST['text']) &&
    isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['user_email'])) {

    /* получатели */
    $to = "ВАШ E-MAIL";

    /* тема/subject */
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $text = $_POST['text'];
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $user_email = $_POST['user_email'];

    /* сообщение */
    $message = '
<html>
<head>
 <title>' . $subject . '</title>
</head>
<body>' . $text . '
</body>
</html>';

    /* Для отправки HTML-почты вы можете установить шапку Content-type. */
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=Windows-1251\r\n";

    /* дополнительные шапки */
    $headers .= "From: " . $user . "<" . $user_email . ">\r\n";

    if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {

        echo "<b>Сообщение отправлено!</b>";

    } else {

        echo "Ошибка отправки!";

    }

} else {

    echo "<font color=red><b>Не заполненны текстовые поля!!!</b></font>";

}
?>
```

Comment: Благодарю!